# How to copy auto-increment id value from one table to another?

Tags: database-design, php, auto-increment

I have a database with two tables, `A` and `B`.

Table `A` contains the `title` of a `book` and has an auto-increment column, `book_id`, that I declared as primary key.

In table `B`, I want to retain the `price` of the `book` having the same `book_id` value. In this case, the `book_id` column will be constrained as a foreign key and I dont want to auto-increment it.

How do I do it using PHP?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (as the syntax is going to vary based on SQL implementation)?  Forget PHP for a minute and think about how you'd go about doing what you want in just SQL ... then if you're unable to convert a pure SQL solution to PHP, post back here with your SQL code and sample PHP attempts.  Also consider reviewing [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Your schema doesn't even make sense. You need to have an authoritative bookid somewhere.

```
CREATE TABLE book (
  bookid  serial PRIMARY KEY
  -- stuff
);

CREATE TABLE book_title (
  bookid  int REFERENCES book,
  title   text
);

CREATE TABLE book_price (
  bookid  int REFERENCES book,
  price   float
);
```

That said, if everything is 1:1 with book, just put it all on the same table. You don't need a separate table for every column:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
  bookid  int serial,
  title   text,
  price   numeric(10,8)
);
```

Comment: I would counter that 'it depends' on what needs to be stored.  If storing historical prices then storing price in a 'history' table may make sense; if the price paid can vary over time, or based on coupons and/or membership levels then price could be stored in an order_item table; if price could vary based on format (hardback, softback, e-book) and/or currency then price could be stored in a separate table based on format/currency; hard to say at this point where price should be saved without a lot of details ... details the OP has not provided eh

Comment: Good Answer, except for the minor issue of `float` being the wrong data type for money.